# Sitecore 6.6 Lucene.Net upgrade issue

Tags: sitecore, lucene.net

I recently upgraded my Sitecore installation from 6.5 to 6.6. Part of this upgrade also upgrades the Lucene.Net library from 2.3.1.3 to 2.9.4.1, which introduces some breaking changes. The code base used a lot of custom code around the Lucene.Net search engine, which had to be removed for the installation to work. Now that I've done that, I'm trying to re-implement the search functions, but I can't get the simplest search to compile. For example, this code:

```
        using (var sc = SearchManager.GetIndex("system").CreateSearchContext())
        {
            var query = new FullTextQuery("health");
            SearchHits hits = sc.Search(query);
        }
```

produces this error:

> Error 104 The type 'Lucene.Net.Search.Query' is defined in an assembly
>   that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'Lucene.Net, Version=2.3.1.3, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'.

I've confirmed that I only have the 2.9.4.1 version of Lucene.Net referenced in my project. Why is this code looking for the 2.3.1.3 version?

Comment: Can you double-check your config files for any references to Lucene, version 2.3.1.3? It is likely that you're referencing the old version in the configs but have referenced the new version in your project.

Comment: Also; make sure your upgrade went through ok. It is an easy mistake to make; to go through with the upgrade, but not clean out 6.5 Sitecore.Kernel DLL files from your various project directories (/obj and /bin in each referenced project).  Make sure to clean out these and rebuild, using 6.6 Sitecore.Kernel

Comment: @Trayek The only place where the version is specifically noted in any of the configs is in the bindingRedirect and it's 2.9.4.1. Is there somewhere else in the configs that could trip it up?

Comment: @MarkCassidy Nailed it - see answer below. That's something I never would have thought of. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

@MarkCassidy nailed it - I did the upgrade on the server, but I was developing locally, so my local copy of the Sitecore.Kernal DLL was still at 6.5. Copying the 6.6 version down locally cleared up the compile error and let me know that my code example is obsolete, which is more along the lines of what I was expecting.